# Windows app works when run in Visual Studio 2019, works after I build and run locally, but when submitted to app store and downloaded, it doesn't run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store

I've built a small windows form app that opens a crm of choice to that customer account by running a command with the incoming phone number to the pbx that is connected to the app.  It hangs out in the task bar and runs in the background.

This app runs beautifully in the IDE visual studio, and then once built and ran from the .exe it runs great too.  However, when submitting it to the Microsoft store and then downloading it, the app doesn't even open.  The window doesn't pop up and close immediately even.  There is no action at all.

I'm confused because it has passed the tests from the store itself but still doesn't work.  I've even tried submitting a practically empty app (removing much functionality) so that I could just see if the window would pop up when I run the app, but still nothing.

I'm fairly new at playing around with these things, but I've spent so much time online in the past two weeks trying to figure out the problem I thought it would be worth asking the great group here.

If you think you need some code, please ask.  At this point, I don't even know what would be helpful to share.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you use .net framework you should insert the framework into the installation file.
or if you use database you should check connection string and insert the database into the installation file and insert the local database( by database version )on the Customer system.

Comment: When you say the installation file, what does that mean?  I see the app.config file and also the package manifest?  It looks like the app.config references `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />`, but does that mean that I also need to have it installed somewhere else?  Or is it not even installed?

Comment: if you use database you should create a installation file.
for create a installation file you should use the visual studio extension or advanced installer or install shield or install aware or ...... software

Comment: I don't use a database. Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Is there a framework version of your application in the downloader system?
Because the default framework in Windows 10 is 4.6

Comment: Yes.  It says .NET Framework 4.7.2.  Underneath that is says "Startup Object" and it was "Not Set".  I chose the program and will try this build and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the issue.  It still does not open.

Comment: Did you run your program on another system?

Comment: Or you can give me the release version of your program for me to test

Comment: I can send you the appxbundle file that we are submitting to the store.  How do I send it to you?

Comment: github or email
can you give me your email?

Comment: my email is jb@vodia.com